# How exactly does Hwoj Wrap work with Bane of the Trapped?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

As I understand it Locust Swarm snapshots on cast, meaning it takes your stats and buffs at the time of cast and will not update new changes until the next cast.

If I have a [Hwoj Wrap](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hwoj-wrap), this makes my Locust Swarm slow enemies.

If I have [Bane of the Trapped](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped) I do bonus damage to enemies that are crowd controlled. This includes slow effects.

If I cast Locust Swarm while wearing Hwoj Wrap and Bane of the Trapped, does this initial cast apply the Bane of the Trapped's extra damage or would I have to cast Locust Swarm twice, once to apply the slow, and then again to snapshot the extra damage the slow grants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After testing this myself I find that the spell Locust Swarm does not snapshot on cast in the manner that I previously thought.

To test this I dismissed my follower and all pets, and used ONLY Locust Swarm to damage my enemies. The very first tic of the dot applied by Locust Swarm was always lower than the subsequent tics, and every tic other than the first was always the same amount of damage.

This tells me locust swarm does its normal damage with the first tic and applies its slow in the same action, then the subsequent tics benefit from the damage increase from Bane of the Trapped.